# Schedule to run a executable jar file on windows 7

Tags: jar, windows-7, scheduled-tasks

I created a task in task scheduler on Windows 7 system and made it repeatable every 10 minutes.

In program, i selected the executable java jar file. But it does not run the jar file at the scheduled time.

When i double click and run the jar file, it runs as desired.
The Jar just pops up a dialog box.

Any inputs as to where i am going wrong is appreciated.

Comment: Post the code you use to run the jar.

Comment: @LaurentiuL. it is a windows-7 system. i added it using control panel->administrative tools -> schedule task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly make sure Java is set in the enviroment `PATH` by opening `cmd.exe` and typing `java -version`. If you get back the java version, then you are fine. (If not see [Update the PATH Environment Variable (Microsoft Windows)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html))

Then create a text file, save it as `run.bat` and type inside:

```
java -jar <insertjavajarnamehere>.jar
```

Make sure the `bat` is in the same directory as your `jar` file.

Now go in **Windows Task Scheduler** > **Create Basic Task** > ... >**Start a program** > and browse for your `.bat` file.

Also, set **Start in** to the path where your `.bat` and `.jar` are located. Create your task and it should run fine afterwards.

**Edit**: To avoid the shell being visible a simple trick is to create a VBS file

Create a run-invisible.vbs, and type:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run("C:\Users\pathtobat\run.bat"), 0, True
```

And schedule that instead of the bat (make sure you update the path to your bat in the vbs file)

Comment: Thanks i thought about this option. Only thing the black command window also opens. Strange windows could not start the executable jar just like we double click and wants us to pack it in a batch file.